# Three.js rotate cube to show selected side in front view?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a rotating box made with three.js and I want to stop (and restart) animation to show the object face frontally.

I would like to show a smooth animation until the cube is in the correct position. I 've seen several examples here on StackOverflow but I wasn't able to replicate it in my example.

**Example**: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/7zqgkuan/)

```
 scene = new THREE.Scene();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.z = 500;

scene.add(camera);

geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Here the animation

```
function render() {

mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
mesh.rotation.z += 0.01;
mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

How is the best approach to keep it simple and smooth?

Answer (score 2):

One approach to solve this problem is the usage of [Quaternion.rotateTowards()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Quaternion.rotateTowards) (a method similar to Unity's [Quaternion.RotateTowards()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html)).

First, you have to define a target rotation for your box. This can be done like so:

```
var targetQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
targetQuaternion.setFromEuler( new THREE.Euler( 0, Math.PI, 0 ) );
```

In the next step, you use `Quaternion.rotateTowards()` in your animation loop like so:

```
if ( ! mesh.quaternion.equals( targetQuaternion ) ) {

    var step = speed * delta;
    mesh.quaternion.rotateTowards( targetQuaternion, step );

}
```

`step` represents the angular displacement in radians per seconds. In the following live example, the value is set to `Math.PI`. Meaning the box can rotate 180 degrees per second.

So essentially, you can define a target rotation for all sides of the cube and then use `Quaternion.rotateTowards()` to rotate towards it.

https://jsfiddle.net/0eutrjqs/

`three.js R113`

Comment: Thanks! I like this one!  I used this array:  var g = [Math.PI,0,Math.PI/2,-Math.PI/2]
       targetQuaternion.setFromEuler( new THREE.Euler( 0, g[s], 0 ) );   
} . here live: https://jsfiddle.net/uncoke/r9xujvs1

Comment: I like this solution but I need to rotate the camera and not the mesh because I have other items on the ground. If I apply the same rotation to the camera (obviously) I lost the object

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm afraid I've misunderstood your post then^^. Anyway, it seems just rotating the camera won't solve the issue since you also need a new position. You can try to animate the camera's position with an animation library like [tween.js](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/) and then use `Camera.lookAt()` per animation step so your camera always looks to a certain target position.